# Ionic Project not created by cmd

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi i m new in ionic when i am run the command "ionic start myApp" nothing is happen and cursor goes to new line in cmd same issue in "ionic --help" please help me. No project is created in my directory location.

Below is cmd command

C:\Users\user>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.7.0

C:\Users\user> ionic start myApp

C:\Users\user>

thanks

Comment: Have you installed all dependency ? Refer this link (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and use command ionic start myApp blank